# PostgreSQL High Disk I/O

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-testing, postgresql-performance

I am evaluating PostgreSQL as an alternative to Oracle. I have a database with 533 Tables which contain up to 250,000 entries.

For a performance comparison, I built the datbase both on Oracle and PostgreSQL.

However, PostgreSQL is much slower, and it doesn't store much in RAM and instead has huge Disk I/O.

**My performance tests:**

- Insert 50,000 entries into a table with roughly 250 columns
- Select all of them including a join on a different table
- Update a string field appending an 'A'
- Dropping an entry in a referenced table which causes all entries to be deleted (on delete cascade)

**My System configuration:**

- Windows 7, 2 Xeons à 8 cores, 32GB Ram, 256GB SSD
- PostgresSQL 9.6
- Oracle XE 11
- MariaDB 10.2

Below is the performance I measured (average of 5 runs):

[image: Comparison]

The NoTriggers version ran with an `ALTER TABLE x DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS`.

As seen in the Chart, PostgreSQL does not really use the available ram.
Looking into the resource monitor, it is indeed using high disk io:

[image: PostgreSQL]

**What I have tried so far:**

- Increasing `effective_cache_size` to 16 GB
- Setting `autovacuum` to `off`
- Setting `max_connections` to 3
- Setting `shared_buffers` to 3GB
- Setting `work_mem` to 512MB
- Setting `maintenance_work_mem` to 64MB
- Setting `synchronous_commit` to `off`
- Even setting `fsync` to `off`

None of these had any impact on either Disk IO or Memory Usage, nor the Performance.

**What am I missing? Is there a flag I missed? Is windows just so bad as a host for PostgreSQL?**

Comment: Windows is definitely not an ideal host for PostgreSQL, but it should be OK for newer PostgreSQL and Windows versions. Windows 7, however, is a pretty bad choice for a benchmark platform for anything. Why benchmark on an *obsolete* consumer version of the OS?

Comment: If there was a monthly prize for the best written question, this would undoubtedly be a contender (+1)! Not an expert, I understand that PostgreSQL defaults are set for servers with low specs - below yours! Have you looked [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization)? Two small points. 1) please don't use images - they work well in this case, but people can't always read them (e.g. me on bus!) - give formatted text also please! 2) I don't think you're allowed publish Oracle benchmarks (just say well known vendor not from Redmond! ;-) ).

Comment: @CraigRinger got in before me - PostgreSQL is not Windows native (but then, neither is Oracle, so...). Also, if you fail to receive a satisfactory answer here, try the PostgreSQL-general mailing list - guys who actually write the server code post there, **regularly**! MfG.

Comment: @Vérace OP has addressed the defaults already, otherwise that'd by my first point.

Comment: BTW, do *not* set `autovacuum` to `off`. It might get you a short term performance boost, but at a growing I/O cost over time as your tables and indexes bloat with dead tuples. If I had to make a guess I'd say the FK constraint is likely the issue, PostgreSQL is less than wonderful at bulk FK cascades.

Comment: @CraigRinger It is the system I work on, which is why I choosed it. Do you think a linux or win10 host would make it better?

Comment: @Vérace thanks! I've already had a look at that page, that is where my changes from the defaults come from.

Comment: @CraigRinger I am just trying to get the maximum performance, since I also set fsync to off. These are of course no settings intended for production

Comment: I guessed that you had done some reading, but it never hurts to point out the basic first steps! :-) Anyway, as I said, not an expert (yet - will be doing a major project with PostgreSQL for my Masters!!), so am not able to just glance at your settings and say "good option/bad option". Why 256 fields per table? That seems a **lot**  to me - even for DW! Are many of them FK's or referred to by other tables? Not really an excuse though - if other (unmentionable :-) ) servers can do it, why not PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Vérace Thats the data model of our software, and I'm evaluating an alternative for Oracle. There are about 20 foreign keys in that table.. However, the layout of the data is nothing I can change

Comment: What are the column data types and size of data? (like INTs or large texts?)

Comment: Did you run ANALYZE after your initial data load? Post your `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) UPDATE ...` (and DELETE) results (or better yet, put the query plans into https://explain.depesz.com/ and post the link the plans). How are you measuring disk I/O? Are all the foreign key fields indexed? `fsync=off` is not a good real-world setting, even though it does give a speed boost at the cost of potential corruption.

Comment: Might be worth posting the output of [pg_test_fsync](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtestfsync.html) too, for more details about your server.